# Why the selected value in a form can not be retrived in the controller using a simple button JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm new to Javascript, and I have a form containing a quiz with 3 radio buttons and 2 navigation buttons (Previous/ Next).

The next button is declared as follows:

```
<button type="submit" class="bouton boutonNav">Suivant</button>
```

In the **Controller** I have to retrieve the selected value by the user, it works with the **Next** button but not for the **Previous** which I wrote it as follow.

```
<button id="btnPrecedent"
        type="button"
        class="bouton boutonNav boutonClair"
        onclick="afficherQuestionPrecedente()">Précédent</button>
```

JS:

```
function afficherQuestionPrecedente() {
    document.location.href = '/outil/UWMI/Accueil/afficherQuestionPrecedente';
}
```

The selected value is always null, but I can't understand why, from a first analysis the only difference between the 2 buttons is that the **Next** button is of type **submit**, so I have added the **type=submit** to the previous but it didn't work also :/.

I tried also the call the submit() form method in the afficherQuestionPrecedente method but it didn't work for me.

```
function afficherQuestionPrecedente() {
    document.location.href = '/outil/UWMI/Accueil/afficherQuestionPrecedente';
    document.fmain.submit();
}
```

Here's the form code:

```
 <web:form title="fmain" id="fmain" class="cadre question"
            action="/outil/UWMI/Accueil/restituerQuestion"
            method="POST">
            <web:grid-column size="24">
                <!-- Formulaire -->
                <!-- Titre de l'étape -->
                <%--                    <c:if test="${clientMif.bloc.nbreQuestion == '1'}">
                </c:if> --%>
                <div class="cadre question">
                    <div class="cadreCorps"
                        style="display: inline-block; padding-left: 0px;">
                        <c:set var="question" value="${clientMif.bloc.questionCourante}" />
                        <web:grid-column size="23" push="1">
                            <div id="titreConfirm">
                                <p>
                                    <c:out value="${question.libelleQuestion}" escapeXml="false" />
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </web:grid-column>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${question.type =='BV'}">
                                <c:forEach var="questReponse" items="${question.reponses}">
                                    <web:grid-column size="23" push="1">
                                        <div class="questionRadio">
                                            <input type="radio" id="${questReponse.id}"
                                                name="${question.idQuestion}" value="${questReponse.id}"
                                                class="questionRadioCheck"
                                                ${questReponse.selected eq 'oui' ? 'checked' : ''} />
                                            <div class="questionRadioCheck"></div>
                                            <label for="${questReponse.id}"> <c:out
                                                    value="${questReponse.libelle}" escapeXml="false" />
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </web:grid-column>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </c:when>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- BoutonsFormulaire -->
                <div class="piedNavBoutons">
                    <button id="btnPrecedent" type="button"
                        class="bouton boutonNav boutonClair"
                        onclick="afficherQuestionPrecedente()">Précédent</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="bouton boutonNav">Suivant</button>
                </div>
            </web:grid-column>
        </web:form>
```

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML, such as the field that has "the selected value". I suggest you wrap in a form tag -  then the submit buttons will send the result

Comment: *"The selected value is always null"* **What** selected value? You haven't shown anything there using a value. Please update the question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Sorry @mplungjan, form added above.

Comment: I would expect both buttons to be submit buttons